# Android TextInputLayout endIconDrawable appears gray instead of image

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-vectordrawable

TextInputLayout endIconDrawable displaying as gray instead of needed image.

Only this image renders as gray. I tried the image as png and also imported svg as vector asset.

Both are not working as expected.

I tried setting image in TextInputLayout:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/chatFragment_TIL1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chatFragment_imageView2"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="@dimen/TIL_CornerRadius2"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="@dimen/TIL_CornerRadius2"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="@dimen/TIL_CornerRadius2"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="@dimen/TIL_CornerRadius2"
            app:endIconMode="custom"
            app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_message_send_icon"
            style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
            app:hintEnabled="false">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/chatFragment_TIET1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:fontFamily="@font/inter_regular"
                android:textColor="@color/black_text_dark"
                android:hint="@string/chatFragment_Text1"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normalText1"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I am also changing it on text input change as below:

```
if(s.length() > 0){
                    inputMessageTIL.setEndIconDrawable(R.drawable.ic_message_send_icon);
                } else {
                    inputMessageTIL.setEndIconDrawable(R.drawable.ic_mic);
                }
```

This is the vectordrawable code:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="32dp"
    android:height="32dp"
    android:viewportWidth="32"
    android:viewportHeight="32">
  <path
      android:pathData="M16,16m-16,0a16,16 0,1 1,32 0a16,16 0,1 1,-32 0"
      android:fillColor="#6B4EFF"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M22.5,9.5L14.25,17.75M22.5,9.5L17.25,24.5L14.25,17.75M22.5,9.5L7.5,14.75L14.25,17.75"
      android:strokeLineJoin="round"
      android:strokeWidth="1.5"
      android:fillColor="#00000000"
      android:strokeColor="#ffffff"
      android:strokeLineCap="round"/>
</vector>
```

This is the image I used in png format
[image: This is the image I used in png format]

This is what I am getting now.. gray circle image..
[image]

Please help me. I can't use another image. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the endIconTint to set the color

```
app:endIconTint="@color/redText"
app:endIconTintMode="multiply"
```

Comment: app:endIconTintMode="multiply" app:endIconTint="@null" - Using this, it works as expected.. Thanks a lot for the answer.. You saved my time..

Comment: Yes, you can use @null to use the color of the image or set a custom tint. Please accept this answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you need to set *more than 1 drawable per case* in code. I solved it using **setEndIconTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST)** :

```
myTextInputLayout.endIconDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.my_drawable, context.theme)
myTextInputLayout.setEndIconTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST)
```